# Are there any known Java class packages for representing a corporation?

Tags: java, data-modeling, organization

Curious if there are any pre-built, well-known/standard, data models for representing a large corporation in Java.  Something that shows a hierarchy as well as "dotted-line" type relationships along with roles.  Trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "representing a corporation" is pretty vague. Can you clarify? It sounds like you are interested in an org-chart kind of thing, but are you just interested in modeling it, or are you also interested in doing stuff like displaying/drawing charts?

Comment: Mainly just representing it for now.  I know how to do it from scratch but I was curious if there were standard structures that should be used for interopability / saving time.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer: there is no such built in data model.

The modelling with a graph, where the graph nodes have names and roles, is not the hardest part. It gots more difficult, when you want an automatic layout such that the corporate graph fits the page.

You could search how Open Source UML Diagramms display their content, and if they use a graphics lib.